# Proper way of saying about continuous time range starting in present and ending at given point in past

Tags: expressions

I would like to stress that something starts now and finishes in the past using the shortest possible form. For example: 
How can I indicate that given time range relates to amount of time someone can move back or rewind a movie ?

I am considering following constructions:
 - "20 seconds from now"
 - "20 seconds since now" 
 - "20 seconds ago"

Is it enough to use any of above form as is or should they be surrounded by some additional words ?
Does any presented form indicate in which time direction speaker/user has to move ?
Does it make sense ?

Comment: maybe " the previous 20 seconds"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- "20 seconds **ago**" : This is probably best. It means a time 20 seconds in the **past**. You could say:

  - "I saw it 20 seconds **ago**."
  - For movies: "Rewind to 20 seconds **ago**." or just "Rewind 20 seconds."
- "20 seconds **from** now" : Usually, this means 20 seconds in the **future**.
- "20 seconds **since** now" : This is very unusual because "since" already means until "now". You could say:

  - "It has been 20 seconds **since** it happened."

You can combine "20 seconds **ago**" with "**from**", "**since**" or "**as of**", *if* you mean something *continuous* over that time:

- "I have been watching since 20 seconds ago."
- "I am a Canadian citizen, as of 20 seconds ago." (slightly formal)
- For movies: "Watch from 20 seconds ago." (This is the opposite of "20 seconds from now".)

Comment: The OP said "_continuous_ time range"...